# React Router not routing to path specified in Route element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the following React app w/ two routes the URL http://myapp routes properly to the Layout component. However, the URL http://myapp/login also routes to the Layout component rather than Login. If I change the path="/login" to "/signin" it routes properly to the Login component.

Is there something special about the "/login" path in React Router that routes it to the route? Or is there an error in the way I've setup this routing?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { NotFound } from './components/NotFound';
import { Login } from './components/Login';

//Redux store
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

function renderApp() {

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Layout} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
  );

}

renderApp();
```

Comment: show your navigation part like link ?

Comment: that seems like it should work, i always find it hard to debug react router so my approach is to haphazardly move stuff around. i'm not aware of there being any special routes in react router - just for sanity's sake, can you move the login route to the top of your switch? are you navigating to login directly or clicking a link to get to it?

Comment: There are no navigation links in the app. if the user enters http://myapp/login in their browser they would get the login component whereas http://myapp would go to the home page. This is because we want a small subset of users to login and decided to make the /login URL more discreet rather than have a login link on the home page.

Comment: Tom Finney - I have moved /login up and it still does not match.

Comment: @ChrisP if you take off the exact prop from the login route, does it match? i always find that about routing issues end up always being super simple/super obvious and make me feel silly afterwards. it seems like a perfectly valid routing set up. is there anything special in your login component like a redirect or something?

Comment: @TomFinney removed "exact" and still does not match. When I put a breakpoint in the Login component constructor it is not reached when /login is used. Seems it's not even getting to the Login component.

Comment: @ChrisP Well I'm stumped! The mystery continues. It definitely works with the `/signin` or any other route except for `/login`? Can you try removing the `basename` prop and see if that would change anything? _clutches at straws_

Comment: @TomFinney When I remove basename it works.??? I'll have to read up more on what impact that attribute has on the routing.

Comment: @ChrisP I can only assume that it was doing something along the lines of prefixing your routes with a slash like `//login` but then that wouldn't explain why `/signin` would work.... I need to read up on it as well!

Comment: It would be nice to mark this as answered and update the question with the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears you have to be careful that the basename attribute is correctly specified for route matching. "/" matches "/login" but "~/" is incorrect. Consider if you need the basename attribute and if so be careful to consider its value.